# .map() isn't replacing string with new dictionary string

Tags: python

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

```
    import glob as glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('CASTp_Total/**/*.pocInfo')

pdb = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/User/Documents/Research/6 - CASTp/CASTp-outputs-v3.xlsx")
code = pdb['PDB code']
long = pdb['CASTp job name (1.4A)']
res = {long[i]: code[i] for i in range(len(long))}

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file , sep ='\t') # if only the first sheet is needed.   
    df['PDB'].map(res)
    df.to_csv(out, sep = '\t')
```

Basically, I've created a dictionary to map over current string in a dataframe. When I run the python script, I end up w/ the same original values, and mapping does not occur. I'm grabbing the dictionary from a very long excel files with too many values to put in this post.

Comment: Since folks don't have your dataset, could you post a [simple reproducible version of it in the post itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)? Also, please show the expected/actual output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to `df['PDB'].map(res)`. Instead of changing the `"PDB"` column in the existing `df` dataframe, your code returns a new dataframe object. Hence, when you do `df.to_csv(out, sep = '\t')`, you still refer to the original, unaltered dataframe.

To solve this, you could replace `df['PDB'].map(res)` by `df['PDB'] = df['PDB'].map(res)`. The loop would then look like this:

```
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file , sep ='\t')
    df['PDB'] = df['PDB'].map(res)
    df.to_csv(out, sep = '\t')
```